# Convert .pages to .doc or .pdf in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, docx, doc

How does one convert a `.pages` file to a `.doc` or `.pdf` file using Python? My use case is basically:

1. User uploads a `.pages` file to my service
2. My service converts the `.pages` to a  .pdf`
3. The `.pdf` is rendered in browser using a browser-based `.pdf` viewer

Answer (score 2):

I've never done it, but it appears the .pages file already contains a pdf version if you unzip the file: [http://blog.cleverly.com/](http://blog.cleverly.com/printer-friendly/346.html)

Comment: This does work, but is not always reliable because the file sometimes contains only the thumbnail.jpg and not the preview.pdf.
Maybe consider something like this instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014807/batch-convert-mac-iwork-files-to-pdf-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

A complete native solution in python will be difficult.

Appropriate solution would be to look at how you can automate pages to export the file in pdf or ms word.

For that, there seems to be an available solution:

1. [pyobjc](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/)

Three is an example that automates pages using pyobjc: http://www.mugginsoft.com/kosmictask/help/automation-python

Comment: I'll add this to my original question, but my use case is:

=> User uploads a .pages file to my service
=> My service converts the .pages to a .pdf
=> The converted .pdf is rendered in-browser using a browser based pdf previewer